# Can this equation have solutions in the upper half complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The equation is $$i\sqrt{\omega^2-p^2}=\frac{A}{1+\frac{i\gamma}{\omega}}$$ where $A,p,\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$, and  $A,p> 0$ and $\omega$ is complex, the solutions of which we seek.

I want to show that $\omega$ cannot have solutions in the upper half complex plane (except for solutions on the real or imaginary axis).

First, consider the **top-right quadrant** in $\omega$ plane. It is mapped by the **RHS** of the equation onto a **quarter** of a **circle** centred at origin restricted to the **bottom-right quadrant** and radius $A$. **LHS** would map the **top-right quadrant** to the **top-left quadrant**. Since the resulting mapped areas of either side of the equation do not coincide no solutions exist in the top-right quadrant.

Repeating the same steps for the top-left quadrant unfortunately does not eliminate it for a region that may contain solutions - if the square root is taken to "turn" the region away from the negative real axis.

Anyone with ideas on how to eliminate the top-left quadrant of the $\omega$ complex plane from possible region of solutions?

Comment: what about $\gamma$??

Comment: @AmerYR $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I was thinking about Rouche theorem